# How do i get a variable from .py file into .kv file Text_Input widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to have a button in my .kv file update a text_input widget in the .kv file with the current time.

I have the current time stored in a variable in a function in the .py file.

```
def get_time(self, event):
    dt3 = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M"))
    return dt3
```

The portion of the .kv file:

```
CustButton:
    text: "Click for current Time"
    on_press: time3=root.get_time('dt3')

CustTextInput:
    id: time3
    hint_text: 
    font_size: 25
```

I'm not getting any errors but when i click nothing happens.  Im not sure if i need to store 'dt3' in an Object Property to pass is to the .kv file.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  I was missing the reference for the hint_text field in the buttons on_press command.  See below for working code:

```
CustButton:
    text: "Click for current Time"
    on_press: time3.hint_text=root.get_time('dt3')

CustTextInput:
    id: time3
    hint_text: ""
    font_size: 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `time3.text = root.get_time('dt3')` instead of `hint_text` and have `readonly: True` in `CustTextInput`. Also it is better to use `on_release` instead of `on_press`

```
CustButton:
    text: "Click for current Time"
    on_release: time3.text=root.get_time('dt3')

CustTextInput:
    id: time3
    text: ""
    readonly: True
    font_size: 25
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i actually did end up changing it to text instead on hint_text already.  Noted about on_release but could you explain why it is better to use this instead of on_press please? Cheers

Comment: It is just the behavior of buttons to do the commands when released (in almost everything else) so it would feel normal to whoever use your kivy app :-)